# Exercise Database with Pictures

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, personal-training

I am finishing designing a personal trainer and fitness app and looking for an exercise database including pictures of the exercises.  I have found a couple different websites, but the information and content is copyright protected.  I am willing to pay for use of the database, but not having any luck on finding such a database.

Comment: How many exercises are you looking to add?  Would it be possible to partner w/ a local gym and make your own database?  Heck, if you do it right, it sounds like you could have an additional revenue stream by allowing people to use your database in application(s).

Answer (score 3):

exrx.net is pretty much the best resource. They have clip-art style pictures and are a suitable paid resource.

Comment: I have seen exrx.net before, but here is their disclaimer; * Although the user agreement permits licence holder to republish Trainer ClipArt on websites, handouts, and other publications; this licence does not permit republishing images within software of any kind (web app, desktop application, mobile app, etc).

Comment: You'll not find a database which just allows reusing their images, try contacting them and figure out a contract. This will likly involve more money than one would spend for a hobby project.